# Python ctypes - call a static inline function in a header file?

Tags: python, c, static, inline, ctypes

I'm working with Python's ctypes to make calls into the Intel Processor Trace library (libipt) on Linux.  One of the initialization functions in the library, pt_config_init(), is defined as a static inline function in the intel-pt.h header file.  When I try to call this function from my Python code, it throws this error:

```
  libipt.pt_config_init(byref(config))
File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 355, in __getattr__
  func = self.__getitem__(name)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 360, in __getitem__
  func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /lib64/libipt.so.1.4.0: undefined symbol: pt_config_init
```

This makes sense, as the function isn't compiled into the library but instead accessed by including the header file in the relevant C sources.  Is there a way to call an inline function like this with ctypes, and if so, how?  Any suggested workarounds if not?

Comment: 1. If it's an `inline` function, it's likely pretty simple; you could just write it in `ctypes` directly. 2. Only "workaround" would be to make a new library that exports a function like: "void inlinewrapper(...) { return inlinefunc(...); }` which should inline the original function into an exported name.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: How you will write a function that uses internal library variables, methods, classes using ctypes? In general it's not possible.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I am new to `ctypes` so for clarity: "config" in the first line of the output above is an instance of a ctypes.Structure class with various \_fields\_ (size, begin, end, etc).  When you say "write it in ctypes directly" do you mean set the Python instance's members directly with Python code in the same way the inline function would have? (e.g. `config.size = 4`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible.

This function not only is not exported by your library, it could not exist at all!

When compiler decides it's worth inlining (keyword is only suggestion)
function body is copy/pasted in all places where normally would be called when not defined inline.